# If a graph $G=\left<V,E\right>$ is connected and $\left|E\right|=\left|V\right|$ then there's a circle in $G$

Tags: graph-theory

> Prove: If a graph, $G =\left<V,E\right>$ is connected and $|E|=|V|$ then there's a cycle in $G$

I think this should be proved by induction. This is certainly holds for $n=1$ (a vertex with a loop).

Now, for the general case, I figure that every vertex in the graph should have degree $2$, which should help with completing the proof. But how exactly?

#### What I did so far:

The equality
$$\sum\limits_{v\in V} d(v) = 2\left|E\right|$$
is true for any graph, and $|E|=|V|$ from the question assumption, so
$$\sum\limits_{v\in V} d(v) = 2\left|V\right|$$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $|E|=|V|=n+1$, and suppose that the result is proved for graphs up to size $n$.

If $G$ has no cycle, it is a tree (by definition).
In a tree, there are vertices of degree $1$ (the leaves), so that let $v$ be a leaf, and let $e$ be the unique edge adjacent to $v$. Then the graph $(V\setminus\{v\}, E\setminus\{e\})$ has $n$ vertices and as many edges as vertices, and it is connected so by induction hypothesis, it has a cycle $e_1\cdots e_k$. Do you see how to finish?

Comment: The finish: If a sub-graph, $G'$ has a cycle, $G$ also has a cycle. Right?

Comment: @Aharon: Exactly. A related exercise is as follows: let $G$ be a connected graph. Then $G$ is a tree if and only if $|E|+1=|V|$. I let you solve this one!

Comment: Thank you, I'll give it a shot!

Comment: Did you remove a leaf from a tree and got a cycle as a result?

Comment: @kuhaku Yes, but fear not, that's because we use a proof by contradiction. The paragraph starts by "If $G$ has no cycle,..." which is obviously an erroneous assumption. Reaching a contradiction, we obtain that $G$ had a cycle, finally.